# Firefox does not show the content-length header using getAllResponseHeaders

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

When trying to get a remote URL file size using XMLHttpRequest and getAllResponseHeaders(),
only Firefox does not return the content-length header at all.
Chrome works.

I've tested this simple code:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    this.getAllResponseHeaders();
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Firefox returns only about 4 response headers and not all of them.
Even though the remote URL has cors enabled.

Comment: Which Firefox version are you testing, works in v70.0.1

Comment: It works with the default file on the example page. Try changing it to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js